# Remove url's appended to url

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

Hi is there any way to disable the url's from appending one after the other as i navigate through the page?

For example, /questions/ displays some questions, and each question has a link to direct to the specific question and display the answers. So i did a

```
<a href="{% url answer.views.display_answers Question.id %}">View answers</a>
```

which changes the url to /questions/1/ on the page. The problem comes when i have a link on the page which brings the user back to the /questions/ page.

```
<a href="{% url 'questions' %}">Back to question list</a>
```

it returns a reversematch error and after some exploring i discovered the mismatch occured because the url is now /questions/1/questions/

So my point is whether there is any way we could control Django appending the url throughout navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be that you're not using quotes consistently in your url template tags.

See the forwards compatibility in the [url template tag docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for more information. I recommend you load the new url tag in both templates, and change the links to

```
{% load url from future %}
...
{% url 'answer.views.display_answers' Question.id %}
```

and

```
{% load url from future %}
...
{% url 'questions' %}
```

If you try that and it still doesn't work, please post your urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{% url answer.views.display_questions %}` instead of `{% url 'questions' %}`, like you already do for the answers.

Comment: @NicholasTeo, of course, the view name itself should be changed to whatever it's actually named. If that's not the issue then I don't know.